# C++ Singleton class - inheritance good practice

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, singleton

In an existing project, I am to inherit a Controller class (MVC) declared as Singleton so as to define my own treatment. How to appropriately derive this Singleton class?

First, I expand on context and need for this inheritance.

The application that I am added to the existing software wants to use a MVC module that performs almost same task as the one I am willing to perform. It is using the same methods up to signature and slight modifications. Rewriting my own MVC module would definitively be duplication of code. The existing module is intrinsically oriented towards its application to another part of the software, and I cannot simply use the same module. But is written as a Model-View-Controller pattern where Controller is Singleton. I derived View already.

Second, I have doubt that I can classicaly derive Singleton class.

Calling constructor from inherited class would simply call getinstance() for parent class and fail to return an object from derived class (?).

Third, it's how I see some way to deal with. Please comment/help me improve!

I copy the whole Singleton class in a class I could call AbstractController. I derive this class twice. The first child is singleton and adopts the whole treatment of parent class. The second child is the Controller for my part of the application, with own redefined treatment.

Thanks!

Comment: For the most part, if a class has a base class that is singleton, then it's completely useless: you can never create any instances of your derived class, because each such instance would also be an instance of the base class, and you're not allowed to make another one of those. (I can imagine "reasonable" exceptions, but only in the case where the base class was designed *specifically* with the idea of being derived in mind....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the situation you're dealing with fully, and whether or not it's possible or appropriate to derive from the singleton depends very much on how the singleton is implemented.

But since you mentioned "good practice" there's some general points that come to mind when reading the question:

1. Inheritance isn't usually the best tool to achieve code re-use. See: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)
2. Using singleton and "good practice" generally do not go together! See: [What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 44):

Truth is, singletons and inheritance do not play well together.

Yeah, yeah, the Singleton lovers and GoF cult will be all over me for this, saying "well, if you make your constructor protected..." and "you don't *have* to have a `getInstance` method on the class, you can put it...", but they're just proving my point.  Singletons have to jump through a number of hoops in order to be both a singleton and a base class.

But just to answer the question, say we have a singleton base class.  It can even to some degree enforce its singleness through inheritance.  (The constructor does one of the few things that can work when it can no longer be private: it throws an exception if another `Base` already exists.)  Say we also have a class `Derived` that inherits from `Base`.  Since we're allowing inheritance, let's also say there can be any number of other subclasses of `Base`, that may or may not inherit from `Derived`.

But there's a problem -- the very one you're either already running into, or will soon.  If we call `Base::getInstance` without having constructed an object already, we'll get a null pointer.  We'd like to get back whatever singleton object exists (it may be a `Base`, and/or a `Derived`, and/or an `Other`).  But it's hard to do so and still follow all the rules, cause there are only a couple of ways to do so -- and all of them have some drawbacks.

- We could just create a `Base` and return it.  Screw `Derived` and `Other`.  End result: `Base::getInstance()` always returns exactly a `Base`.  The child classes never get to play.  Kinda defeats the purpose, IMO.
- We could put a `getInstance` of our own in our derived class, and have the caller say `Derived::getInstance()` if they specifically want a `Derived`.  This significantly increases coupling (because a caller now has to know to specifically request a `Derived`, and ends up tying itself to that implementation).
- We could do a variant of that last one -- but instead of getting the instance, the function just creates one.  (While we're at it, let's rename the function to `initInstance`, since we don't particularly care what it gets -- we're just calling it so that it creates a new `Derived` and sets that as the One True Instance.)

So (barring any oddness unaccounted for yet), it works out kinda like this...

```
class Base {
    static Base * theOneTrueInstance;

  public:
    static Base & getInstance() {
        if (!theOneTrueInstance) initInstance();
        return *theOneTrueInstance;
    }
    static void initInstance() { new Base; }

  protected:
    Base() {
         if (theOneTrueInstance) throw std::logic_error("Instance already exists");
         theOneTrueInstance = this;
    }

    virtual ~Base() { } // so random strangers can't delete me
};

Base* Base::theOneTrueInstance = 0;


class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    static void initInstance() {
        new Derived;  // Derived() calls Base(), which sets this as "the instance"
    }

  protected:
    Derived() { }   // so we can't be instantiated by outsiders
    ~Derived() { }  // so random strangers can't delete me
};
```

In your init code, you say `Base::initInstance();` or `Derived::initInstance();`, depending on which type you want the singleton to be, and when you want a pointer to the singleton, you call `Base::getInstance()`.  You'll have to cast the return value in order to use any `Derived`-specific functions, of course, but without casting you can use any functions defined by `Base`, including virtual functions overridden by `Derived`.

Note that this way of doing it also has a number of drawbacks of its own, though:

- It puts most of the burden of enforcing singleness on the base class.  If the base doesn't have this or similar functionality, and you can't change it, you're kinda screwed.
- The base class can't take *all* of the responsibility, though -- each class needs to declare a protected destructor, or someone could come along and delete the one instance after casting it (in)appropriately, and the whole thing goes to hell.  What's worse, this can't be enforced by the compiler.
- Because we're using protected destructors to prevent some random schmuck from deleting our instance, unless the compiler's smarter than i fear it is, even the runtime won't be able to properly delete your instance when the program ends.  Bye bye, RAII...hello "memory leak detected" warnings.  (Of course the memory will eventually be reclaimed by any decent OS.  But if the destructor doesn't run, you can't depend on it to do cleanup for you.  You'll need to call a cleanup function of some sort before you exit, and that won't give you anywhere near the same assurances that RAII can give you.)
- It exposes an `initInstance` method that, IMO, doesn't really belong in an API everyone can see.  If you wanted, you could make `initInstance` private and let your init function be a `friend`, but then your class is making assumptions about code outside itself, and the coupling thing comes back into play.

Also note that the code above is not at all thread safe.  If you need that, you're on your own.

Seriously, the less painful route is to forget trying to enforce singleness.  The least complicated way to ensure that there's only one instance is to only *create* one.  If you need to use it multiple places, consider dependency injection.  (The non-framework version of that amounts to "pass the object to stuff that needs it".  :P )  I went and designed the above stuff just to try and prove myself wrong about singletons and inheritance, and just reaffirmed to myself how evil the combination is.  I wouldn't recommend ever actually doing it in real code.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and thoroughly detailed and has some colorful language and humor.  It's amazing it flew under the SO radar.

Comment: "It puts most of the burden of enforcing singleness on the base class." - In some cases this might be exactly what we want. Say, we expose the base class instance as an Api to external world and hide the derived class, which can be referenced by internal code only.

Comment: @ShibirBasak: Problem is, it's literally never exactly what you want. It causes more problems than it can solve. For example, it's only "most" because it *can't* be "all". Both sides have to play their parts just so, or you lose all guarantees the Singleton pattern is designed to offer. And once you're ready to abandon those, you've tossed out your reason to follow the pattern in the first place.

Comment: The sample code should contain the client code also. It is not clear how future clients will acquire a (the) Derived instance.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the similar need in my app... in any case here is my out of code implementation :

h.

```
    class icProjectManagerHandler;
    class icProjectManager : public bs::icBaseManager {
        friend class icProjectManagerHandler;
    protected:
        icProjectManager();
    public:
        ~icProjectManager();

        template<typename t>
        static t *PM() {
            return dynamic_cast<t *>(icProjectManagerHandler::PMH()->mCurrentManager);
        };
        template<typename t>
        static t *PMS() {
            static icProjectManagerHandler pm;
            return static_cast<t *>(icProjectManagerHandler::PMH()->mCurrentManager);
        };
    };

    class icProjectManagerHandler {
        friend class icProjectManager;
        icProjectManager *mCurrentManager;
        icProjectManagerHandler();
    public:
        ~icProjectManagerHandler();
        static icProjectManagerHandler *PMH();

        inline void setProjectManager(icProjectManager *pm) {
            if (mCurrentManager) { delete mCurrentManager; }
            mCurrentManager = pm;
        }
    };
```

Cpp.

```
    icProjectManagerHandler::icProjectManagerHandler() {
        mCurrentManager = new icProjectManager();
    }
    icProjectManagerHandler::~icProjectManagerHandler() {

    }
    icProjectManagerHandler *icProjectManagerHandler::PMH() {
        static icProjectManagerHandler pmh;
        return &pmh;
    }
    icProjectManager::icProjectManager() {

    }
    icProjectManager::~icProjectManager() {

    }
```

And example:

```
class icProjectX : public ic::project::icProjectManager {
public:
    icProjectX() {};
    ~icProjectX() {};
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    auto pro = new icProjectX();
    pro->setIcName("Hello");
    ic::project::icProjectManagerHandler::PMH()->setProjectManager(pro);
    qDebug() << "\n" << pro << "\n" << ic::project::icProjectManager::PMS<icProjectX>();
    return 10;
}
```

The issue of this implementation is that you have to initialize your "singleton" class 1st or else you will get the default base class. But other than that... it should work?