# Vala: How to refer an abstract class' subclass?

Tags: singleton, abstract, vala

Consider the following:

```
abstract class Singleton : Object {
    private static Singleton _instance = null;
    public static Singleton instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = // constructor call goes here
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

class Foo : Singleton {
    Foo() {}
}

var test = Foo.instance();
```

I would like to implement a singleton in an abstract class. My question is: How can I refer to the subclass constructor from `Singleton.instance()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance and the singleton pattern don't mix well:

[C++ Singleton class - inheritance good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370749/c-singleton-class-inheritance-good-practice)

Why don't you just make your Foo class static (make all members static):

```
public class Foo {
    // Static constructor
    public static Foo() {}
    // Static methods
    public static void bar () {}
    // Static attributes, etc.
}
```

This usually works as well. It does not work so well if your "singleton" has a costly construction and you want to avoid it being always constructed.